# Merge Sort in java

Tags: java, mergesort

This code is a simple merge sort by divide and conquer analogy. I'm getting an unsorted array as output which is the same as the input array. Please point out the bug in this code:

```
import java.util.*;
class Merge {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int n,i;
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("enter size of array");
        n = sc.nextInt();
        int b[] = new int[n];
        System.out.println("enter  array");
        for (i=0;i<n;i++) {
            b[i] = sc.nextInt();
        }
        System.out.println("sorted array");
        int c[] = sort(b);
        for (i=0;i<n;i++) {
            System.out.println(c[i]);
        }  
    }
    static int[] sort(int[] a) {   
        int i;
        int l = a.length;
        if (l<2) {
            return a;
        }
        int mid = l/2;
        int left[] = new int[mid];
        int right[] = new int[l - mid];
        for (i=0;i<mid;i++) {
            left[i] = a[i];
        }
        for (i=mid;i<l;i++) {
            right[i-mid] = a[i];
        }
        sort(left);
        sort(right);
        merge(left,right,a);
        return a;
    }
    static void merge(int[] left , int[] right , int[] a) {
        int p=0,q=0,r=0;
        while (p<left.length && q<right.length) {
            if (left[p]<=left[q]) {
                a[r] = left[p];
                p++;
            } else {
                a[r] = right[q];
                q++;
            }
            r++;
        }
        while (p<left.length) {
            a[r] = left[p];
            p++;
            r++;
        }
        while (q<right.length) {
            a[r] = right[q];
            q++;
            r++;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Run it through a debugger.

Comment: I would recommend you use a debugger and try to figure it out yourself. That would help you way more and you would learn some useful things as well.

Answer (score 1):

in your merge method you have problem with your condition

```
         if (left[p]<=left[q]) {
```

it should be

```
          if (left[p]<=right[q]) {
```